# Cookies does not work in Firefox and Opera - but work fine in Chrome and Edge

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies, .net-core

I have a strange problem with a c# core mvc project.

Cookies I set don't work in Firefox and Opera (they are simply not set, without error in console or elsewhere) - but work fine in Chrome and Edge. The cookies from the framework (e.g. .AspNetCore.Identity.Application) work - login therefore works, but custom functions do not - even in development environment. So I am confused why this does not work.

Here code example how I set cookies in controllers:

```
CookieOptions options = new CookieOptions();
options.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);
options.HttpOnly = true;
options.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
Response.Cookies.Append("testcookie", "true", options);
```

For samesite option I tried lax and strict - without change.

I am thankful for hints and solutions, what this can be due to

Thanks

Comment: Your code appears to be correct... Did you tried without `SameSite`? Check your browser settings to be sure they're not blocking cookies in some way.

Comment: Problem solved - it was due to the Consent - I had disabled the popup because an advertising service provider asks for it - but the Consent was still enabled in the startup and therefore had not allowed special cookies. But no error or anything else was written. Now I set "options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;" in startup